# How do I render one property object array to flat array in python flask sqlalchemy marshmallow app?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am writing Python Flask WebApp first time. Using Flask, SQLAlchemy, Marshmallow as my primary packages. I have a nested schema, but in the parent page I am not displaying children, but I want to bring all children ids into the parent, so that in details page I can load all children. I trimmed down the children to only return ids, but then I don't want those as one property objects, but want ids array instead.

How do I change JSON like this,

```
{
  "description": "Report Name",
  "id": 1,
  "load_date_time": "2019-02-12T05:14:28+00:00",
  "children": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "publish_date_time": "2018-09-03T00:00:00+00:00",
  "summary": "Summary will also be present. Usually two to three brief sentences about the content on the detail page."
}
```

to,

```
{
  "description": "Report Name",
  "id": 1,
  "load_date_time": "2019-02-12T05:14:28+00:00",
  "children": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  "publish_date_time": "2018-09-03T00:00:00+00:00",
  "summary": "Summary will also be present. Usually two to three brief sentences about the content on the detail page."
}
```

Marshmallow Schemas:

```
class ChildIdSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('id', )
        ordered = True

class ParentSchema(ma.Schema):
    children = fields.Nested('ChildIdSchema', many=True)
    class Meta:
        # Fields to expose
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'children', 'summary', 'load_date_time', 'publish_date_time')
        ordered = True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using marshmallow 3, you can use the [`Pluck`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/api_reference.html#marshmallow.utils.pluck) field for that.

With marshmallow 2, use the `only` parameter to [`Nested`](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/2.x-line/api_reference.html#marshmallow.fields.Nested).

```
# 2.x
class ParentSchema(ma.Schema):
    children = fields.Nested('ChildIdSchema', many=True, only='id')

# 3.x
class ParentSchema(ma.Schema):
    children = fields.Pluck('ChildIdSchema', 'id', many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using list comprehension as follows:

```py
d['children'] = [v for child in d['children'] for k,v in child.items()]
```

Comment: I am not writing any loop or anything, data coming from database mysql and I have schemas to render data to json. Updating my question with Schemas.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish. It sounds like something else needs to be done in the process of making the json file, and there isn't enough information here to help with that.

Comment: I have updated my question if you want to have a look at it again. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This is my first Python code. I am kind of confused myself yet. But will try to keep updating my question.